# How to close other windows in tmux?

Tags: bash, vim, tmux

I write some functions in `.bashrc` to make `tmux` easy to use:

```
#!/bin/bash
# .bashrc

# vim            tmux
#-----  --------------------
tabc()  { tmux kill-window; }
tabe()  { tmux new-window; }
tabf()  { tmux find-window $@; }
tabn()  { tmux next-window; }
tabo()  { ; }                         # <-- How to `tabonly`?
tabp()  { tmux previous-window; }
qa()    { tmux kill-session; }
sp()    { tmux split-window; }
vsp()   { tmux split-window -h; }
on()    { tmux kill-pane -a; }

typeset -fx tab{c,e,f,n,o,p} {,v}sp qa on
```

I want to implement the [`tabonly`](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=201108092124.15908.richard.foley@rfi.net&forum_name=tmux-users) command, but don't know how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the window you want to keep as the current window, just call `next-window` and `kill-window` repeatedly, until `next-window` fails:

```
while tmux next-window 2> /dev/null; do
    tmux kill-window
done
```

Comment: The next release of *tmux* (i.e. 1.7) will have `kill-window -a` to kill all windows except the current window.

Answer (score 5):

For easy copying, tmux >= 1.7:

```
tabo()  { tmux kill-window -a; }
```

Thanks Chris Johnsen.